# '++' is deprecated: it will be removed in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

After update to `Xcode 7.3`, there are bunch of warnings showing in my project.

> '++' is deprecated: it will be removed in **Swift 3**

Any idea to fix this warning ? Any reasons why the `++` and `--` will be deprecated in the future ?

Comment: Definitely a duplicate... although that question is about the _beta_ (and is dated Feb 3), while this one is about the _official release_ (dated Mar 23, days after Xcode 7.3 hit the Store)... What does one do in such a case?

Comment: @NicolasMiari Just vote to close it. It's still Xcode 7.3, we can only edit the question to remove "beta".

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Since Swift 2.2, you should  use `+= 1` or `-= 1` instead.

And after looking up Swift's evolution, there are some reasons for removing these operators:

> 1. These operators increase the burden to learn Swift as a first programming language - or any other case where you don't already know these operators from a different language.
> 2. Their expressive advantage is minimal - x++ is not much shorter than x += 1.
> 3. Swift already deviates from C in that the =, += and other assignment-like operations returns Void (for a number of reasons). These operators are inconsistent with that model.
> 4. Swift has powerful features that eliminate many of the common reasons you'd use ++i in a C-style for loop in other languages, so these are relatively infrequently used in well-written Swift code. These features include the for-in loop, ranges, enumerate, map, etc.
> 5. Code that actually uses the result value of these operators is often confusing and subtle to a reader/maintainer of code. They encourage "overly tricky" code which may be cute, but difficult to understand.
> 6. While Swift has well defined order of evaluation, any code that depended on it (like foo(++a, a++)) would be undesirable even if it was well-defined.
> 7. These operators are applicable to relatively few types: integer and floating point scalars, and iterator-like concepts. They do not apply to complex numbers, matrices, etc.
>
> Finally, these fail the metric of "if we didn't already have these, would we add them to Swift 3?"

Please check out [Swift evolution](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0004-remove-pre-post-inc-decrement.md#disadvantages-of-these-operators) for more info.

Comment: if `x + = 1 represent  x++ ` ;
what if `++x` ?

Comment: I want to see source or proof of number 1,5,6

Comment: stupid idea. Swift full of all kinds of brand new syntax sugar, but they removing classic... nonsense