# Deprecations to syntax such as ++, --, and C-style loops in preparation for the future Swift 3 release

Tags: swift, for-loop, xcode7.3, swift3

Why does Apple hate ++ and -- operators in the 'for' loop? I mean the following comment in the release notes of the latest Xcode 7.3:

> Deprecations to syntax such as ++, --, and C-style loops in
>   preparation for the future Swift 3 release

Comment: One more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173096/is-deprecated-it-will-be-removed-in-swift-3?lq=1