# ++ is deprecated it will be removed in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

++ will be deprecated in swift 3

variable++
can now be written as

```
variable += 1
```

How can I rewrite `++variable`.

Please recall difference between `++variable` and `variable++` syntax

Comment: Makes no difference. It isn't what you say, it's when you say it. If _you_ understand the difference between `++variable` and `variable++`, this is obvious. If not, please read my now-oh-so-tediously-revised answer.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366847/what-is-the-difference-between-pre-increment-and-post-increment-in-the-cycle-fo?answertab=votes#tab-top. Should apply in Swift too.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173096/is-deprecated-it-will-be-removed-in-swift-3

Comment: @matt: I still don't get it. Why did you vote to "close as unclear what you're asking"? – You answered the question 2 minutes after it were asked, so it must have been clear to you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Rewrite it as:

```
variable += 1
```

...exactly as the warning message suggests. This will now need to be a separate line, of course (that's the only bad thing about this change). What matters is *where* you put that line.

---

So for example

```
let otherVariable = ++variable // variable is a previously defined var
```

now becomes

```
variable += 1 // variable is _still_ a previously defined var
let otherVariable = variable
```

---

But on the other hand

```
let otherVariable = variable++ // variable is a previously defined var
```

now becomes

```
let otherVariable = variable
variable += 1 // variable is _still_ a previously defined var
```

---

**Extra for experts:** In the rare situation where you `return variable++` — that is, you return `variable`, which is in a higher scope, and *then* increment it — you can solve the problem like this:

```
defer {
    variable += 1
}
return variable
```

Comment: I think author asks about different syntax `++var` and `var++`. How first variant should be fixed?

Comment: @sage444 Same way. It's as plain as plain can be. The problem is that `++` is not; that's why it's being abolished. Most people don't even understand the difference between preincrement and postincrement. So now you just increment — at the moment when it makes sense to do so.

Comment: It gets a bit more complicated when you're using a postincrement expression as a return value `return index++` ;)

Comment: @vadian, I think that's Matt's point. The behavior of `return index++` is subtle and likely lost on naive developers. In the interest of clarity, subtle is bad.

Comment: Out of scope question, why did they depreciate it?

Comment: @OmarBizreh https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0004-remove-pre-post-inc-decrement.md

Comment: @vadian added a postscript to my answer, explaining how to do `return index++`

Comment: Wow, this is pretty nifty :-)

Comment: @vadian I thought you knew this and were just yanking my chain. :)

Comment: I must admit that `defer` didn't come at all to my mind

Answer (score 1):

You can write `variable += 1` on the line above. Implement a preincrement by incrementing, before.