# What's the difference between a defer statement and a statement right just before return?

Tags: ios, swift, deferred

What's the difference between this:

```
_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

defer {
    let rootVC = navigationController?.topViewController as? RootViewVC
    rootVC?.openLink(url: url)
}
return
```

and this:

```
_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

let rootVC = navigationController?.topViewController as? RootViewVC
rootVC?.openLink(url: url)
return
```

Apple's swift guideline says: “You use a defer statement to execute a set of statements just before code execution leaves the current block of code. ”,but still I don't quite get it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> What's the difference between a defer statement and a statement right just before return?

All the difference in the world. The `defer` statement is executed *after* the return! This allows you to accomplish things that can be accomplished in no other way.

For example, you can return a value and *then* change the value. Apple makes use of this trick quite regularly; here, for example, is code from the Sequence documentation showing how to write a custom Sequence:

```
struct Countdown: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
    var count: Int

    mutating func next() -> Int? {
        if count == 0 {
            return nil
        } else {
            defer { count -= 1 }
            return count
        }
    }
}
```

If you wrote that as

```
            count -= 1
            return count
```

... it would break; we don't want to decrement `count` and then return it, we want to return `count` and then decrement it.

Also, as has been already pointed out, the `defer` statement is executed no matter *how* you exit. And it works no matter you exit the current *scope*, which might not involve `return` at all; `defer` works for a function body, a while block, an if construct, a do block, and so on. A single `return` is not the only way to exit such a scope! There might be more than one `return` in your method, and/or you might throw an error, and/or you might have a `break`, etc. etc., or you might just reach the last line of the scope naturally; the `defer` is executed in every possible case. Writing the same code "by hand", so as to cover every possible exit, can be very error-prone.

Comment: Are you sure defer statement is executed after the return? Swift programming language guide book says: "Use defer to write a block of code that is executed after all other code in the function, just before the function returns”。It says "before the function returns".

Comment: Tried running in playground, defer statement was not called after return

Comment: the statements in the defer block are executed when the execution leaves the current scope. It has nothing to do with the before/after "return". What If the function has no return in it !

Comment: @Shubham Yes, that’s what I said too, in the third paragraph. Defer is executed because we have left, no matter how. See http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_defer And did you follow the link and study this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36185126/341994

Comment: @matt that's a nice example with incrementing the int. I guess that the int value is captured before executing the defer statement, and the defer statement is executed before the flow resumes in the calling code.

Comment: @matt To me it seems you are agreeing with Shubham where he says "It has nothing to do with the before/after return", there by contradicting your answer where you say "The defer statement is executed **after** the return"

Comment: @BangOperator Read my comment again. He says "what if the function has no return in it?" I say that exit is exit no matter how; return is just one special case. But it is the special case that my answer deals with, because that's what the question was. — Also please see the link given in my answer; there is no need to deface my answer by adding an example that I already give.

Comment: now I got the difference. The end of scope could be actually the end of an *if* statement. I thought _scope_ was referred to the function scope. Thank you @matt

Comment: Instead of defer, just count -=1 first, then return (count+1).

Answer (score 18):

In your example there is actually no difference, but please look at this:

```
func foo(url: URL) -> Int
    let fileDescriptor : CInt = open(url.path, O_EVTONLY);
    defer {
      close(fileDescriptor)
    }
    guard let bar = something1() else { return 1 }
    guard let baz = something2() else { return 2 }
    doSomethingElse(bar, baz)
    return 3
}
```

`close(fileDescriptor)` is always executed regardless in which line the function returns.

Answer (score 9):

defer statement is used to execute a piece of code exactly before the execution departs the recent scope.

For example:

```
func defer()  { 
 print("Beginning") 
 var value: String? 
 defer { 
    if let v = value { 
        print("Ending execution of \(v)")
    } 
 } 
 value = "defer function" 
 print("Ending")
}
```

First line which will print is: Beginning

Second line which will print is: Ending

And the last line which will print is: Ending execution of defer function.

Answer (score 4):

Using `defer` lets you avoid conditional clean-up at the end of the function.

Consider this example:

```
class Demo {
    var a : String
    init(_ a:String) {
        self.a = a
    }
    func finish() {
        print("Finishing \(a)")
    }
}

func play(_ n:Int) {
    let x = Demo("x")
    defer { x.finish() }
    if (n < 2) {return}
    let y = Demo("y")
    defer { y.finish() }
    if (n < 3) {return}
    let z = Demo("z")
    defer { z.finish() }
}

play(1)
play(2)
play(3)
```

Function `play` creates one, two, or three `Demo` objects depending on its parameter, and calls `finish` on them at the end of the run. If the function returns from the middle, `defer` statements do not get executed, and `finish` is not called for objects that never get created.

An alternative to this would require using optionals:

```
func play(_ n:Int) {
    var x:Demo? = nil
    var y:Demo? = nil
    var z:Demo? = nil
    x = Demo("x")
    if (n >= 2) {
        y = Demo("y")
    }
    if (n >= 3) {
        z = Demo("z")
    }
    x?.finish()
    y?.finish()
    z?.finish()
}
```

This approach places all declarations at the top, and forces you to unwrap optionals later on. The code with `defer`, on the other hand, lets you write clean-up code near the code that does initialization.