# Check if string is part of array of tuples - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples, element

I'm trying to figure out how to check if a string passed to a function can be found in an array that is comprised of tuples as elements. Below is my code. I'm not sure how best to fix this.

```
typealias myTuple = (input: String, magnitude: Int)    

var userInput = "Happy"                               

var wordOneArray: [myTuple] = [] 

var magnitudeCount = 1

var userInputTuple: myTuple = (userInput, magnitudeCount)


magnitudeCount += magnitudeCound

func addUserInput(tempArray: myTuple) {    

    if wordOneArray.contains(userInput) {

        userInputTuple = (userInput, magnitudeCount += magnitudeCount)

    }

    wordOneArray.append(userInputTuple)

    print(wordOneArray)


}

addUserInput(tempArray: userInputTuple)

userInput = "Sad"

userInputTuple = (userInput, magnitudeCount)

addUserInput(tempArray: userInputTuple)
```

Comment: What's your expected output? What errors do you get, and on what lines?

Comment: I get an error on the if statement line "missing argument label 'where:' in call. I also get an error in the next line that says '+=' produces '()', not the expected contextual result type 'Int'. I'm not sure why on the second. The first error fix doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with this information. The reason for the first error is that you cannot directly ask if an array of tuples contains a string – you'll have to use a custom predicate (hence why the compiler is suggesting `contains(where:)`). The reason for the second error is that `+=` returns `Void`. You need to move it out of the tuple assignment, and just assign `magnitudeCount` instead – see for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/36185088/2976878

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your code doesn't compile :/

In any case, you can use `wordOneArray.contains(where: { $0.0 == userInput })` to find out if the tuple contains the string.

Comment: thank you. will this search for that particular string in all tuples of the array? or just the first?

Comment: It will loop through the entire array until it finds a tuple with a matching string and returns `true` if it does, if it doesn't it will return `false` instead.

Comment: ok awesome. that worked well. The only last piece is that I am trying to then increment the "magnitudeCount" of the given tuple element it finds. I've modified my code but it doesn't give the right output.. (also, Stackoverflow won't allow me to paste my code here, it says it's too long for a comment). Do you have any ideas of how I could increment the magnitudeCount if a match is found?

Comment: Sure, just increment on a line before passing it into the tuple: 

```magnitudeCount += magnitudeCount```
```userInputTuple = (userInput, magnitudeCount)```

Comment: ah ok I see what you're saying, however the function first has to check if the userInput is in the array and if it is, then magnitudeCount *of that specific String* is incremented. So I might have some issues since magnitudeCount isn't tied to a specific string yet.

Comment: Well, no, because you can't get to this line `userInputTuple = (userInput, magnitudeCount)` without ` if wordOneArray.contains(where: { $0.0 == userInput }) {}` being true. So long as you add `magnitudeCount += magnitudeCount` inside that if statement, but before passing it into the tuple (i.e. on the line before, like I said) then it will only update the magnitude when that string is found.